# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'tuple' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x

я новичок в питоне, задали найти дистанцию между точками. Вот что у меня получилось:

```
from typing import Tuple

import math

def distance(pointA: Tuple[float, float], pointB: Tuple[float, float]) -> float:
    
return math.sqrt((pointA)**2 + (pointB)**2)
```

Далее вставляю значения:

```
distance((1, 1), (5, 4))
```

И программа выдает ошибку:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'tuple' and 'int'

Объясните пожалуйста, где ошибка

Comment: Какой результат ты ждёшь от (1,1)**2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вероятнее всего надо так:

```
def distance(pointA: Tuple[float, float], pointB: Tuple[float, float]) -> float:
    
    return math.sqrt((pointA[0] - PointB[0])**2 + (PointA[1] -pointB[1])**2)
```

Answer (score 2):

вообще-то формула для расстояния:

```
d^2 = dx^2 + dy^2
```

а ваша формула

```
math.sqrt((pointA)**2 + (pointB)**2)
```

что считать должна?

ну и конечно вы пытаетесь выполнить `(pointA)**2`, т.е. повести в квадрат совокупность из двух чисел - это как? что это должно значить?

правильнее было бы

```
dx = pointA[0] - pointB[0]
dy = pointA[1] - pointB[1]

d = (dx**2 + dy**2)**0.5
```

P.S.

для многомерного евклидово пространства функция должна быть такой:

```
def distance(pointA, pointB) -> float:
    return sum((point[0] - point[1])**2 for point in zip(pointA, pointB))**0.5
```